# Is it still an instance of the interface? PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

if I have a function as such:

```
public function(Some\Namespace\Interface $instanceOfInterface) { ... }
```

And I have the following inheritance:

```
class Something implements Some\Namespace\Interface { .... }

class SomethingElse extends Something { ... }
```

will the function above work if I pass it an instance of `SomethingElse` ?? Or do I have to pass it a direct instantiation of a class that directly inherits from the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code says it, SomethingElse "extends" (specializes) Something, that implements the API as asked by Interface. So SomethingElse also implements the Interface.
That's the magic of interface :)

Answer (score 0):

It should work, inheritance in PHP supports grandfathering.

Meaning so long as you've declared properly, any children of children should have access to the parents public methods and will be instances of any implementations along the way.

[heres](http://www.elated.com/articles/object-oriented-php-working-with-inheritance/) a useful resource that might help